# jQuery clone - data post to php function

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Here is my form element

```
<form method="post" id="add_facility_form" class="blocks" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/facility_management/add">
     <div id="contact_wrapper">
                 <p>Name: </p>
                  <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="contact_name[]" />
                  <p>Department: </p>
                  <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="department_name[]" />
                  <p>Email: </p>
                  <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="contact_email[]" />
                  <p>Phone number: </p>
                   <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="contact_phone_number[]" />
                   <p>Fax number: </p>
                   <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="contact_fax_number[]" />

            </div>
             <img width="21" height="21" alt="" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/forms/icon_plus.gif" class="add_new_contact add_new" />   
</form>
```

when I click on the image it clones the whole div.I want to post the data but the problem is that it posts only first div's information.How can I post the cloned element's data?

here is jquery function and php

```
$(".add_new_contact").click(function () {

        $("#contact_wrapper").clone().attr('id','contact_wrapper'+new Date().getTime()).appendTo($(this).parent());
        return false;
    });
```

PHP

```
$contact_name = $this->input->post('contact_name');
        $department = $this->input->post('department_name');
        $contact_phone = $this->input->post('contact_phone_number');
        $contact_fax = $this->input->post('contact_fax_number');
        $contact_email = $this->input->post('contact_email');
        $contact_count = count($contact_name);
```

Comment: Just in case the helpers you are using to access the form data acts in a strange way, check the content of $_POST. I would also check what is sent over using FireBug.

Comment: I checked the $_POST array. It shows data of only original elements.

Comment: Did you check the DOM model to make sure the elements are added within the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

    $array=$_POST['contact_name'];
    foreach($array as $name)
    {
            echo "Name is ".$name."<br>";
    }


    $array=$_POST['contact_email'];
    foreach($array as $email)
    {
            echo "email is ".$email."<br>";
    }

    ?>
```